# Здравствуйте друзья, только учу JavaScript, мне немного непонятны некоторые моменты,помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

Пришел вот к такому решению интересному, может кому пригодится:

```js
    function getFizzBuzz(num) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  
      switch(0) { //Результат сравнения
                             
        case Number(!(!(i % 3) && !(i % 5))):   //Условия
          console.log("fizzbuzz");
            break; 
          
        case (i % 3):
          console.log("fizz");
            break;
  
        case (i % 5):
         console.log("buzz");
            break;
  
        default:
          console.log(i);
            break;
      } 
    } 
  }
  
  let num = +prompt("Please, write any number: ", 0);
  getFizzBuzz(num);
```

Подскажите, я правильно понимаю этот фрагмент кода? Вроде как думал так и написал, он еще работает когда я пишу просто `(!(i % 3) && (i % 5))`, но тогда он так и останется `Boolean` значением получается?

Пишем `Number(!)` для того чтобы преобразовать код внутри скобок `Number` к логическому типу, чтобы работал оператор `&&`, иначе оператор сравнения `&&` работать не будет. далее опять преобразуем к логическому типу `!(i % 3)` и `!(i % 5)`, в итоге все преобразуется к числовому типу на выходе, так как вначале стоит `Number` преобразователь.

Comment: в case добавь `break`

Comment: Не будет работать же, просто числа выводит, что с break что с continue что без

Comment: `switch(i)` => `switch(true)`

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл точно!

Comment: В case нужно писать значение i, а вы пишете туда булевы, которые получаются после операторов сравнения и &&.

Comment: было бы не плохо ознакомится о оператом switch более подробно дабы не писать условия в case https://learn.javascript.ru/switch

Comment: Было бы неплохо давать вопросам названия отражающие твою проблему, а не писать эту ерунду в заголовке.

Comment: Решение перенесите в ответ (в вопросе должен быть только вопрос), дайте вопросу нормальный заголовок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор switch последовательно сравнит "a" со всеми вариантами из case.

case  является ответом на вопрос "чему равно А".
switch является тем местом, куда можно записать условие.

```
switch(i % 3){ 
   case 'если результат i % 3  равен такому-то, тогда': console.log(i + ' такой-то');
}
```

Вы  можете использовать условие в  case, тогда switch должен являться boolean type.

```
function getFizzBuzz (num) {
   for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
       switch(true) {
           case i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0:
               console.log("fizzbuzz"); 
               break;
           case i % 3 == 0:
               console.log("fizz");  
               break;
           case i % 5 == 0:
               console.log("buzz"); 
               break;
           default: 
               console.log(i); 
               break;
       }
   }
}

let num = +prompt("Please, write any number: ", 0);
getFizzBuzz(num);
```

Comment: Да, про него забыл,  добавлю, извини. был не прав!